# rules_invoke_event() not working with 'user_login'

Tags: hooks, rules

Very broadly, I want to know how to use the `rules_invoke_event()` for the event listed in the admin UI as "User has logged in". The parameters I passed to the above function were 'user_login' and $GLOBALS['user'].

I have a few rules which govern the redirection when a user logs in. I want this redirection to work in some other place where the user_login hook is not fired.

I have tried to use the

```
rules_invoke_event('user_login', $account)
```

But I am getting a white screen when this part is run. If I replace it with a `drupal_goto`, it works.

> **Note 1:** In the admin UI, the event is "User has logged in", the
>   `user_login` was found in `rules_user_login()`, which uses the same call
>   as above.
>
> **Note 2:** the `$account` used here is `global $user`, or `$GLOBALS['user']`.

What am I doing wrong here? I suspect something is wrong with the parameters passed to the function '`rules_invoke_event`'. On omitting the `$account` argument, there is an error that says that a token is missing.

Also, there is a function `rules_event_invocation_enabled` which is supposed to toggle whether the rule events can be called. I have tried to fire the function with both `rules_event_invocation_enabled(TRUE)` and `rules_event_invocation_enabled(FALSE)` before the `rules_invoke_event('user_login', $account)`